# Returning a list of objects with exact matching of the field list

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entieties in my database.

```
@Entity
public class First {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Second> secondSet;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Second {
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    private First first;
    ...
}
```

And in `FirstRepository extends JpaRepository<First, Long>` I want to create method

```
List<First> findAllBySecondSet(List<Second> secondList);
```

This method should return a list of `First` objects that have exactly the same database objects in the `secondSet` field as the objects sent in the `SecondList` list as the method parameter.

Is there a simple JPQL query that allows this operation?

I know, that when I create something like that:

```
@Query("select f from First f join fetch f.secondSet s where s in :secondList")
List<First> findAllBySecondSet(@Param("secondList") List<Second> secondList);
```

I will get a list of `First` objects that have any of the list objects. But I want **exactly** the same objects. No less no more.

Comment: That's not possible with a simple query.

Comment: But what if we allow more complex methods?